# Timeout error when using features_from_place

Tags: python, openstreetmap, osmnx

I'm trying to execute the following to get all buildings within Manhattan in Python on Google Colab

```
tags = {
    'building': True
}

# Geocode the location to get its geometries
ft = ox.geocode_to_gdf('Manhattan Island')

# Extract the polygon geometry from the GeoDataFrame
polygon_geometry = ft.geometry.iloc[0]

# Retrieve features within the polygon with specified tags
buildings_net = ox.features_from_polygon(polygon_geometry, tags=tags)
```

for some reason, I get this error

> TimeoutError                              Traceback (most recent call
> last)
> /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in
> _make_request(self, conn, method, url, body, headers, retries, timeout, chunked, response_conn, preload_content, decode_content,
> enforce_content_length)
> 536         try:
> --> 537             response = conn.getresponse()
> 538         except (BaseSSLError, OSError) as e:
>
> 23 frames TimeoutError: The read operation timed out
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> ReadTimeoutError                          Traceback (most recent call
> last) ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='overpass-api.de',
> port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=180)
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> ReadTimeout                               Traceback (most recent call
> last) /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py in
> send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
> 530                 raise SSLError(e, request=request)
> 531             elif isinstance(e, ReadTimeoutError):
> --> 532                 raise ReadTimeout(e, request=request)
> 533             elif isinstance(e, _InvalidHeader):
> 534                 raise InvalidHeader(e, request=request)
>
> ReadTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='overpass-api.de', port=443):
> Read timed out. (read timeout=180)

I was initially trying to do the following (which does work), you need to specify the distance since it seems to only get by default a 100. I just was to get all the buildings in the region by itself without needing to specify a distance.

```
tags = {
    'building': True
}
# need to change this distance to capture the entire city
building_network = ox.features_from_address('Manhattan Island', tags, dist=3000)
```

Is there a way to go around this timeout error?